# Getting error instead of empty schema in Sanity

Tags: schema, sanity

I set up the project and everything went right but when I run the npm run dev command in vs code, in Sanity, I am getting an error.

> No document types

Please define at least one document type in your schema.

I was expecting an empty schema. Any idea why am I getting the error?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Object types no longer listed if no document types found
Previously, if your schema did not contain any document types, the desk tool would instead show object types. This functionality is now removed, and will instead show a descriptive error message.